# Disable/Enable touchpad hotkey does not work in 23.04

Tags: touchpad

So, pressing Fn+F5 on my Dell laptop displays the overlay symbol, and toggles touchpad slider in the settings.
But both the hotkey, and the settings have no effect on the touchpad.
Using xinput --disable 16 works fine

So - I am looking for where to correct Ubuntu's / Gnome's behavior.
I am NOT looking for yet another script to issue those commands.
I mean ..this is open source, it must be possible to make it toggle the correct device?

Comment: "both the hotkey, and the settings have no effect on the panel.": what do you mean by "the panel"? Question is somewhat unclear

Comment: sorry, "panel" should be "touchpad"
Additional info: this works for me; [ "$(xinput list-props 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad' | grep 'Device Enabled' | grep -o '[01]$')" == "1" ] && xinput --disable 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad' || xinput --enable 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad' 
- but I'd like the actual Fn+F5 to do the job

Comment: It might be good to edit your question to clarify it rather than clarifying it in a comment. Not everybody will read through all comments.